# include jQuery to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, include

I was working with jQuery on https://codepen.io/ and to include jQuery is very easy. So i decided to work on files on my computer, i tried to include it using the file and it didn't work. also i tried to include from CDN but still doesn't work.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/Web.js"></script>
```

and in the Web.js i put this code:

```
<button id="btn">Hide</button>
<p id="para">A dpara.</p>
```

Comment: Can you please give more detail than 'it doesn't work'. Can you give a full example of your code, along with any errors that appear in the console (press F12 to see it)

Comment: and what is the error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: May i ask why do you put html code inside js file?

Comment: Unless there's a network problem at your end, the "include" of jQuery isn't the problem. That script tag is correct and the path is valid.

Comment: @AlanBns: To improve the question, use the "edit" link on the question, not comments.

Comment: Please add real code to the question - I could not salvage your comment

Answer (score 1):

Your `Web.js` isn't a javascript file, but rather an HTML-file.
You want to create a new HTML file named for example `index.html`.
You fill this one up like so:

```
<!--  index.html: -->
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Web.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="btn">Hide</button>
    <p id="para">A dpara.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

You should be able to use jQuery as you wish now.

Also, this is the folder structure you should have with the above example:

- index.html
- js
- - Web.js